# Declare and assign variable to an object in PHP/Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter, I retrieve database results and store it in a variable like the following:

```
$data['user'] = $this->some_model->get_by_id($id);
```

Say the above retrieves only the user_id and the user_name, so the variables will be

```
$data['user']->user_id;

$data['user']->user_name;
```

Now, say, I want to assign another value (eg. age), can I do the following?

```
$data['user']->age = '23';
```

Comment: Technically, yes, you can. But it's bad practice.

Comment: Yes, you can. Its only temporary. The actual database record does not change.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the age will be calculated in PHP and used just to display it to the user by passing it to the view. I don't need the database record to change.

@JohnConde Why is it bad practice? Does it have any adverse affect, besides just being mere bad practice?

Comment: Assigning values to undeclared object properties is "expensive" in PHP. Plus it is not always clearer to the reader where a value came from so this make code maintenance more difficult.

Comment: Making all of this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes, you can. But it's bad practice. Assigning values to undeclared object properties is "expensive" in PHP. Plus it is not always clear to the reader where a value came from so this make code maintenance more difficult.